# Ascertaining Valve Part Numbers

Tags: identification, vacuum-tube, vintage

Old valves (vacuum tubes) sometimes do not come in their original boxes. Sometimes the part numbers seem impossible to read. Is there an easy way to read an apparently illegible part number? Would UV light bring up the number? Would chalk be relevant? How did the old timers deal with this problem in the day?

Comment: I am fairly certain in the old times they had fresh paint and proper packaging.

Comment: Old timers didn't have to deal with the problem because the valves came new and in original boxes.

Comment: @Jim Dearden .I remember having this problem with my junk box valves in the 1970s when I was at school .

Comment: I remember back to the late 1950s ... However, you can probably work out roughly what the valve (type) is by looking at it i.e. type of base, physical size and internal structure. The fact you can't read the number would probably indicate its long passed its sell-by date.

Comment: I assume that these are solenoid-driven valves, given that you've posted on electrical engineering?

Comment: @Reinderien Valves aka "thermionic valves" are a British English term for vacuum tubes, I think receiving tubes in particular. It is known in most of the Commonwealth, save perhaps Canada which is influenced by US terminology more than the rest of the world.

Comment: **valve**
valv/, *noun*,

a device for controlling the passage of fluid or air through a pipe, duct, etc., especially an automatic device allowing movement in one direction only. [In this case it's electrons through a vacuum. The earliest valves were probably rectifiers - a non-return valve.]

Comment: Fascinating! And your observation on us Canadians is correct.

Comment: I believe that breathing on the tube could sometimes make the number readable - moisture in the breath acted differently on the lettering than on the plain glass.